# Sorting vector of instances

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am currently taking a coding class at university and they have VERY specific requirements for the homework assignments.

For this week we have a class called `Npt` that represents a Nobel Prize winner.  This class contains, amongst other things, the Name, the year of the prize and the field of the winner.

Now we should make another class, `Nobelpreise`, that contains a container for instances of said Nobel prize winner class.  We are supposed to sort the elements of that container by the year of the Nobel Prize.

I wasn't able to use the `std::sort` function with a custom comparator correctly.  This is what my code roughly looks like:

```
class Nobelpreise
{
private:
 int numb;
 vector<Npt> xx;
public:
 Nobelpreise(){numb=0;}
 void add(Npt &n1){xx.push_back(n1);numb++;return;}
 Npt get_nobel(int i) {return xx[i];}
 vector<Npt> get_xx() {return xx;}
 int get_numb(){return numb;}
 ~Nobelpreise(){}
 bool mycomp(Npt N1, Npt N2) {return (N1.get_jverl()<N2.get_jverl());}  
 };
```

The method `get_jverl()` comes from the `Npt` class and just returns the year.

Now the sort function always gives back an error saying that:

```
sort(Npl.get_xx().begin(), Npl.get_xx().end(), Npl.mycomp)
```

requires two arguments.  Shouldn’t they be provided by the sort function?
I have also tried to overload the `<` operator which does not seem to work either.

edit1: added end() and removed the () from `Npl.mycomp`
edit2: we are required to make the comparator function a member of the class

Comment: Congratulations. You are passing two iterators pointing to two *unrelated* copies of the classes members to `sort`. That *really* has to hurt...

Comment: The compiler says that `mycomp`, not `sort`, requires two arguments. Don't *call* the function when you sort, just pass it. And make it a free function instead of a member function.

Comment: You're also missing parens when calling `.end()`

Comment: ... and you don't need `numb`, because you can get `xx.size()`. In fact, you don't need ths class at all :)

Comment: you are excately right, the problem just is that the requirements of the exercises are stupidly strict

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/731986c47a235702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your method `mycomp` static, and write a method which does the sort job.

```
class Nobelpreise
{
private:
    int numb;
    vector<Npt> xx;
public:
    Nobelpreise(){numb=0;}
    ~Nobelpreise(){}
    vector<Npt>& get_xx() {return xx;}

    static bool mycomp( const Npt &N1, const Npt &N2 ) { return N1.get_jverl() < N2.get_jverl(); }
  //^^^^^^

    void Sort() { std::sort( xx.begin(), xx.end(), &mycomp ); }
};
```

The method `Npt::get_jverl` has to be const

*returntype* `get_jverl() const { return ...; }`

If you do the sorting outside your class note that you have to return a reference to your vector in your method: `vector<Npt>& get_xx() {return xx;}`

```
sort(Npl.get_xx().begin(), Npl.get_xx().end(), &Nobelpreise::mycomp)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, I still can't seem to get it working if I execute your code I get a passing 'const Npt' as 'this' argument of 'int Npt::get_verl()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]. Is there a mistake in my Npt class?

Comment: thanks, somehow I have still got an error in my code whenever I try your first suggestion I get an error saying: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Npt&' from expression of type 'const Npt', what does that mean, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ok cool, now the code complies fine but I still get an error when I execute the script: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Comparators should generally take things by const-reference, not by value or reference. Also, I understand you want to give the OP options, but making the struct the comparator is terribly unidiomatic and bizarre.

Comment: I have now made the Npt::get_jverl() method const, the code compiles fine and I still get that segmentation fault (core dumped)-error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok, thanks I'm still looking and can't find anything so far. My Nobelpreise Class is not inhertiting from the Npt class and the comparator and the Sort function are both in the Nobelpreise class not in the Npt, could this be a problem?

Comment: ok then what could be the cause of the segmentation fault? It seems to happen during the sorting or just right after, since I can get std::cout just fine before I call Npt.Sort() and nothing afterwards

Comment: you are right, I have taken a closer look at the sorting, everything goes fine until i reach the data of Albert Einstein, can't figure out why though

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we'll fix the error that you're fetching two instances of the list:

```
sort(Npl.get_xx().begin(), Npl.get_xx().end, Npl.mycomp());
```

Replace with

```
auto v = Npl.get_xx();
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Npl.mycomp());
```

I've added `()` to `v.end`, too, as we want to call it.  However, we *don't* mean to call `Npl::mycomp()` here - `std::sort` wants to receive a function, not the return value:

```
auto v = Npl.get_xx();
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Npl::mycomp);
```

This still won't work, as `Npl::mycomp` is an instance method, and `std::sort` won't call it with an object pointer for `this`.  As it's implementation doesn't use `this`, it can be made a static method.  Better still, it doesn't use any of the private members, so can be made a free function, outside of any class:

```
// I've renamed this to say what it does
bool year_precedes(const Npt& a, const Npt& b) {
    return a.get_jverl() < b.get_jverl();
}

class Nobelpreise; // make the full declaration available
                   // for the following to compile

// I've made this a nonmember, too, as it only uses public methods
vector<Npt> sorted_prizes(const Nobelpreise& p)
{
    auto v = p.get_xx();
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), year_precedes);
    return v;
}
```

That should be enough to help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of C++, but assuming C++11 here's a more modern approach (compared to the two answers that are already here). Your requirements don't mention needing the comparator for anything else, so rather than write a comparator, you can do this:

```
std::sort(Npl.get_xx().begin(), Npl.get_xx().end(), [](const Npt& lhs, const Npt& rhs) {
  return lhs.get_jverl() < rhs.get_jverl()
});
```

You could put this code in the Sort method of the Nobelpreise class as Rabbid suggests.

Compared to the other approaches here, I'd argue it makes the code more readable as you can see inline what is being compared, instead of having to jump to a new function just to read one more line of code (assuming of course that function is not being used anywhere else). It also makes the code faster because you are passing a lambda rather than a function pointer, but you shouldn't necessarily worry about that at this stage.